# Drawing gradient on BlackBerry 10 (Cascades and C++)

Tags: gradient, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Is there any way to draw a simple linear gradient in Cascades or/and C++? I've found an example using QtQuick library (https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qmlreusablecomponents.html), but it doesn't work. Even the import of this library isn't recognized by Momentics

Comment: It does appear to be a valid question. Wondering why no one has answered it. For me it appears likes the documentation is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately gradients are not possible to do that way in Cascades.

I would recommend using an gradient image and [ImagePaintDefinition](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__imagepaintdefinition.html). For example:

```
Container {
    layout: DockLayout {

    }
    preferredHeight: constants.headerHeight
    minHeight: preferredHeight
    maxHeight: preferredHeight

    minWidth: constants.screenWidth
    background: back.imagePaint

    attachedObjects: [
        Constants {
            id: constants
        },
        ImagePaintDefinition {
            id: back
            imageSource: "asset:///images/header_solid.png"
            repeatPattern: RepeatPattern.X
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ergin, I hoped that there's another way, but this will help too